# How do you resize a form to fit its content automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to implement the following behaviour:

On a form there is a tabcontrol. On that tabcontrol there is a treeview. To prevent scrollbars appearing, I would like the form to change its size according to the contents of the treeview when displayed for the first time.

If the treeview has too many nodes to be displayed on the default size of the form, the form should change it's size so that there is no vertical scrollbar on the treeview (up to a maximum size allowed by the size of the screen).

What I need to know is, if it is possible to achieve this behaviour through the properties of the controls. I'm sure this can be achieved by calculating and settings the sizes of the elements programmatically, but I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this by settings like AutoSizeMode etc.

**[UPDATE]**

It's the first dialog a user of my application sees: It's a dialog to select the database to work with. It's a list of databases, with a tabcontrol, buttens etc. If the list is too long, scrollbars appear and a colleague of mine wants them to disappear.

Answer (score 34):

Use the AutoSize and AutoSizeMode properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize.aspx

An example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // no smaller than design time size
    this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width, this.Height);

    // no larger than screen size
    this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight);

    this.AutoSize = true;
    this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

    // rest of your code here...
}
```

Comment: I tried doing something like this but I found that this approach in conjunction with docking and anchors made for really weird behavior sometimes. So by itself it might work fine but if you have any sort of docking then it may not be worth the trouble.

Comment: System.Windows.SystemParameters is obsolete and will not work with current versions of .NET. Consider revising.

Comment: i tried this but i still can't get the form to grow when the contents of a centrally anchored listbox increase. instead i get a scrollbar in the listbox. I don't see any autosize properties on the listbox itself. i am guessing i need to place it in a auto sized panel as dock-full ?

Comment: I wanted to add items, resize, and then allow the user to resize too. So what I did was `AutoSize = true; OnResize(e);` which resized to fit the new controls, then saved that new size `var newSize = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width, this.Height);` then turn off autosize so it remains user controlled. However on doing so the form snaps back to its previous size, so you can force it via `this.Size = newSize`. And Viola! Autosize on demand and remains user adjustable. Thought I should share.

Answer (score 19):

By using the various sizing properties (Dock, Anchor) or container controls (Panel, TableLayoutPanel, FlowLayoutPanel, etc.) you can only dictate the size from the outer control down to the inner controls. But there is nothing (working) within the .Net framework that allows to dictate the size of a container through the size of the child control. I also missed this a few times and tried the AutoSize property, but it never worked.

So all you can do is trying to get this stuff done manually, sorry.

Comment: yes, in that direction I have always done it manually too. @jgaufin's cautions do apply!

Comment: Actually, the AutoSize property *does* work, just not very well, especially if you have also tried to dock or anchor any of the contained controls. WinForms will usually just have a mental breakdown at that point. You should autosize the container to the controls *or* anchor/dock the controls to the container, but never both. Actually, scratch that... just avoid AutoSize. Your sanity will thank you.

Comment: Agreed, avoid using autosize even it can work. Another big reason not to use it is because it prevents the user from being able to manual change a form's size at runtime. You almost always want the user to be able to manually control a form's size, and if you do want to automatically size the form it's usually accompanied by an event, so just handle the event with some code to do the resizing rather than set the property of your entire form's behavior to autosize.

Comment: You can also un-dock, autosize, and re-dock... 

`dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.None;
dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;
this.AutoSize = true;
dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

Answer (score 13):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171729.aspx):

> To maximize productivity, the Windows Forms Designer shadows the
>   `AutoSize` property for the `Form` class. **At design time**, the form
>   behaves as though the `AutoSize` property is set to **false**,
>   regardless of its actual setting. **At runtime**, no special
>   accommodation is made, and the `AutoSize` property is applied as
>   specified by the property setting.

Answer (score 7):

This might be useful.
It resizes a new form to a user control, and then anchors the user control to the new form:

```
Form f = new Form();
MyUserControl muc = new MyUserControl();
f.ClientSize = muc.Size;
f.Controls.Add(muc);
muc.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
f.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 5):

You could calculate the required height of the TreeView, by figuring out the height of a node, multiplying it by the number of nodes, then setting the form's MinimumSize property accordingly.

```
// assuming the treeview is populated!
nodeHeight = treeview1.Nodes[0].Bounds.Height;

this.MaximumSize = new Size(someMaximumWidth, someMaximumHeight);

int requiredFormHeight = (treeView1.GetNodeCount(true) * nodeHeight);

this.MinimumSize = new Size(this.Width, requiredFormHeight);
```

NB. This assumes though that the treeview1 is the only control on the form. When setting the requiredFormHeight variable you'll need to allow for other controls and height requirements surrounding the treeview, such as the tabcontrol you mentioned.

*(I would however agree with @jgauffin and assess the rationale behind the requirement to resize a form everytime it loads without the user's consent - maybe let the user position and size the form and remember that instead??)*

Comment: I had to create my own implementation of "Alert Dialog" mimicking the original .NET Dialog Window. In my case, I need to create a dialog window that would fit the dynamically generated label text inside the form. So, basically I just have to measure the dynamic control height and width inside the window, and adjust the width and height `MinimumSize` attribute of the form just like this answer do.  And I set the `AutoSize` property of the control and the form itself to `true`. Fine tune the control with its `MaximumSize` attribute

Answer (score 4):

This technique solved my problem:

**In parent form:**

```
frmEmployee frm = new frmEmployee();
frm.MdiParent = this;
frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
frm.Show();
```

**In the child form (Load event):**

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you trying to fit the content according to the forms than the following will help. It helps me while I was trying to fit the content on the form to fit when ever the forms were resized.

> this.contents.Size = new Size(this.ClientRectangle.Width,
>   this.ClientRectangle.Height);

Answer (score 1):

I User this Code in my project, Useful for me.

```
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int w = MainPanel.Width; // you can use form.width when you don't use panels

        w = (w - 120)/4; // 120 because set 15px for each side of panels
                         // and put panels in FlowLayoutPanel
                         // 4 because i have 4 panel boxes
        panel1.Width = w;
        panel2.Width = w;
        panel3.Width = w;
        panel4.Width = w;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it works just fine

```
const int margin = 5;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.X + margin,
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Y + margin,
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 2 * margin,
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - 2 * (margin - 7));
        this.Bounds = rect;
```