# How to have PictureBoxs adjust height, width, and location to a form when form size changes?

Tags: c#, forms, resize, picturebox

How can I have my picturebox's adjust their height, width, and location relative to the size of the form? Right now I have the default looking like this:

[image: og]

but if I resize it with my mouse it looks like this:

[image]

How can I get it so that it fills in the spaces correctly and propotionally (relative to the form's dimensions)?

Here is what I have tried:

```
   private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //adjust the size of the tiles relative to the dimension of the window
            if (Size != new Size(442, 465)) {//the default size of the form
                for (int i = 0; i < picBox.Length; i++) {
                    picBox[i].Height = Size.Height / 4;//picBox is an array of PictureBoxs with default heights, widths, and locations
                    picBox[i].Width = Size.Width / 4;
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962595/how-do-you-resize-a-form-to-fit-its-content-automatically) because I'm trying to have my contents adjust to the size of the form, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoSize to force a form to resize to fit its contents.
A form does not automatically resize in the Visual Studio forms designer, regardless of the values of the AutoSize and AutoSizeMode properties. The form correctly resizes itself at run time according to the values of these two properties. By contrast, a custom UserControl automatically resizes itself both at design time and at run time.
When using AutoSize, the MinimumSize and MaximumSize properties are respected, but the current value of the Size property is ignored. Using AutoSize and AutoSizeMode also renders the AutoScroll property superfluous, as there is no way to shrink the form to hide its contained controls from view.
See the AutoSizeMode enumeration for information on how a form behaves when AutoSize is true.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AutoSize = true;
    this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
}
```

refer [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx) microsoft link for more info

There are some limitations in winforms application to make variable size of window at runtime. In you case I would suggest just don't let user resize the window but make his application window fit to his screen resolution by below code on form load event.

```
this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I try that it won't even let me change the size...

Comment: Please refer this, There are limitations of Winforms http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962595/how-do-you-resize-a-form-to-fit-its-content-automatically

Comment: I have tried that too but no luck.

Comment: I updated answer just try to follow same aproach