# How to make a Windows Form to change it height adaptively as controls get added/removed or hidden/shown?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

What I need can probably be described as "reverse-anchor", "reverse-dock" or something like that (I have chosen to mention this just because "reverse-anchor" happened to be the first thing to come into my mind as a keyword candidate when searching for questions and answers that might already have been submitted discussing this subject, perhaps this will help people thinking a similar way to find this one in  future). WinForms controls implement the `Anchor` property to set up adaptive resizing on containing control/form size change but I need the opposite - the form to resize adaptively to the controls.

A thing adding a minor bit of complexity to the task is that the controls meant to be added/removed/shown/hidden/enabled/disabled (and resized perhaps - this functionality is not really needed directly so far but I suspect it can turn to be required for compatibility with non-default Windows visual styles and themes that have potential to affect controls sizes unpredictably and can change at any moment of the app running) are not going to be the last ones on the form - a row of buttons will always be in between of the last control of the volatile group and the window lower border.

The actual task is to design a form that will display a collection of objects with a row of controls (a label, a text box and 0-2 buttons) corresponding each of them and it is strongly preferable to use just the very basic "common controls" avoiding grids, lists and stuff like that in this case (wrapping them in an additional container controls like panels is perfectly acceptable though, abstracting them in a separate "user control" can be considered too if this can really make the solution easier, more reliable or otherwise better, using hand-written code manipulating controls and form sizes is perfectly acceptable too (I can hardly expect a "set a magic property and it's done" kind of solution to exist for this task) but I haven't found a reliable algorithm so far (when to change what properties and what formulae to calculate new values with)).

The maximum capacity can be safely limited to something near 10 (or 20, perhaps, but not more - more would be just absolutely unreasonable to display on one form (provided scrolling is not an option)) so both ways are acceptable: to add/remove the controls in runtime or to put them on the form in the designer and just manipulate `Visible` and/or `Enabled` properties in the code. By the way I have found a problem with `Visible` - it gets switched off and back on by the framework internals before the form is rendered and other controls `Anchor` properties come in the game but I don't think it's a good idea to rely on this to happen always and the same way so just adjusting the form `Size` property on a control `Visible` property change does not feel really convenient).

What might be some good ideas relevant to implementing this behaviour?

PS: As far as I know this is a natural feature of WPF but I am to use WinForms to make the app runnable on Macs and, perhaps, other non-Windows platforms with help of Mono.

Comment: Is it similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962595/how-do-you-resize-a-form-to-fit-its-content-automatically

Comment: @Srikanth thanks! I have spent some time searching for something relevant but, to my surprise, couldn't find anything. Now I'll study that question and answers to it and delete this question perhaps If I don't find that one different in some significant ways.

Comment: There are too many ways to do this.  Probably a FlowLayoutPanel with AutoSize = true, the form's AutoSize = true and usercontrols in the FLP for the "rows" is easiest.  Users don't like a main window that has no well-defined size btw, they'll probably just maximize it.

Comment: @HansPassant do you mean all the things you have mentioned to be used together at the same time? As for the UX part - the size will rarely (if ever) be changed after the form is displayed actually and the maximise button will be disabled as it is going to be a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you about some clues may help you:

1- correct to build your own Procedure for manipulating all the matter.

2- i advice to use a Wizard methodology (Next / Back buttons) so if the plate form is small like tablet or smart phone, so the mentioned procedure will decide how many Controls combinations (Label, text box, option button...) will be in each frame of that wizard and keep the remaining for Next button.

**3- By the way if you will hide some controls use the original event fires to run the mentioned Procedure. (like a basic button to start the form so don't depend on visible / resize events).**

4- Resize the size of each form of the wizard in the last part of the mentioned procedure.

If still a problem exists tell me and i hope i can help :-)

Comment: Thanks but the wizard way is really an overkill. Although I've mentioned up to 20 fields as a reasonable limit and an a rejected idea of possibly displaying even more, more than something around 5 control rows (each one being just as high as a button is by default) to display is going to be an extremely rare case. The actual count will almost always be something like 2-4 and will hardly ever (really, I just can't imagine such a situation) come close to 10. The form I'm designing is a generic/flexible kind of dialog to just ask the user to set a couple of parameters quickly, and press ok/cancel