# How to re-size a form to contain its controls in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: screenshot]

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.

As shown in `screenshot` I have `Form1` which has `flowLayoutPanel1` and `ButtonCancel`.

When `Form1` loads, number of `buttons` are added into the `flowLayoutPanel1` (the number of buttons is changing and it is not fixed).

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
            {

            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = i.ToString();  
            btn.Width = 104;
            btn.Height = 63;
            btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;              
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);

            }
 }
```

Problem:

The problem is that there is a gap that I want to remove, to do that I have to reduce `Form1` Height according to the number of the added `buttons` but I do not know how to resize `Form1` Height based on the number of added `buttons`.

For example, if 2 `buttons` are added I want `Form1` to shrink to fit the 2 `buttons` and if 8 `buttons` are added I want `Form1` to expand to fit the 8 `buttons` without leaving gap.

Is there any `Form` `property` allows `Form1` to expand and shrink according to the number of added `buttons`?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe flow layout panel isn't best control in this case. What about simply docking?

Comment: `Form.Height = numberOfButtons * 63 /*button height */;`

Comment: Set [AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autosizemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Do you mean that (1) the number of buttons is not known up front and (2) the buttons have to be fixed size and (3) the user cannot resize the form?

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov. I sat both Form1 and layout pane to GrowAndShrink but nothing changed and the gap still there.

Comment: @mikelegg. number of buttons is known but it's changing,

Comment: @ Adriano Repetti . I made similar to this but it is not accurate and sometimes it leaves gap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you resize a form to fit its content automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962595/how-do-you-resize-a-form-to-fit-its-content-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

- Put a `TableLayoutPanel` with one column and two rows on the Form
- Set the `Dock`-property of the `TableLayoutPanel` to `Fill`
- Set the `Size-Type` of the first row of the `TableLayoutPanel` to Percent -> 100%
- Set the `Size-Type` of the second row of the `TableLayoutPanel` to Absolute -> 63 Pixel
- Put the `FlowLayoutPanel` inside the first row
- Put the Cancel-`Button` inside the second row
- Set the `AutoSize`-property of `Form`, `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel` to `True`
- Set the `AutoSizeMode`-property of `Form`, `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel` to `GrowAndShrink`

Comment: I tried it but the buttons are added from left to right. do you know how to add them from top to bottom? tnx

Comment: Set the `FlowDirection` of the FlowLayoutPanel to `TopDown`

Comment: I tried exactly what you said, all worded good but the cancel button which is in the second row is not showing up? any idea? tnx

Comment: Not sure, maybe you didn't drop it properly inside the TableLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable docking then it will resize automatically