# Auto size winform to fit dynamically created buttons c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a flowlayoutPanel inside a winform, I create a ton of buttons dynamically but Im coming across an issue where some buttons are not visible due to the size of the winform.

Here is my code currently:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var v in KeyValuePairs)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = v.Value;
        b.AccessibleName = v.Key.ToString() ;
        b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        b.Location = new Point(startposition, endPosition);
        b.BackColor = Color.White;
        b.Width = 90;
        b.Height = 40;
        b.Margin = new Padding(5);
        b.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
        endPosition += 100;            
    }
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(endPosition, endPosition);
}
```

How can I get the winform to flow with n number of buttons? Is there a proper way of doing this? I am not using any anchoring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you resize a form to fit its content automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962595/how-do-you-resize-a-form-to-fit-its-content-automatically)

Comment: If your panel is say 100x100, everytime its size is changed, add/subtract the change to the main form. You can subscribe to resize event or whatever the event is called and put the required code in there. The autosize mode out of the box doesn't work well. During design time, make the form look as you desire with a single button or so, then use those numbers as guide.

Comment: @ADyson would that go before my snippet or after?

CodingYoshi You are saying that link isn't the best option do you have a snippet i could reference to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: "would that go"...would what go? There are several potential solutions posted in that link, I've no idea which one you're referring to.

Comment: If using a `FlowLayoutPanel` then you don't specify the `Location`, the panel takes care of that. You might want to try the `WrapContents = true;` option.

Comment: @Loathing that did the trick, you want to submit the answer and I can select yours as the answer? Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `WrapContents = true;` option.

Comment: Thank you this was the best answer, I then just used: locationOnForm = b.FindForm().PointToClient(b.Parent.PointToScreen(b.Location)); to find the last Y value and then add a few to the integer to increase the height of the form.

Comment: @student The proper way to do that is: `FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel { WrapContents = true, Dock = DockStyle.Fill }; // add buttons in for-loop; Size sz = panel.GetPreferredSize(new Size(400, int.MaxValue)); f.Controls.Add(panel); f.ClientSize = sz;` Where `400` is your desired width.